# Are XML and JSON used to *communicate* information between a client and a server?

Tags: json, xml, http

Are XML and JSON used to transfer data between  client and server applications, or are they just containers to store this data on a computer? By transfer, I do not refer to sending an XML/JSON file as an email attachment.

Let's say I'm on a stock app or a weather app (or pages in a  browser), and I query a stock price or the weather in my town. Is the app sending an HTTP request to the weather/stock server or is it sending some kind of XML/JSON request?

Comment: HTTP is the protocol; XML/JSON are two possible ways of encoding the request payload. Think of HTTP as the envelope and XML/JSON as the letter -- assuming the metaphor of paper mail can still be considered alive in this day and age... The direct response to your question "is it for transfer or is it for storage" is "why not both", but *realistically* they're mostly used as intermediate formats rather than the final resting place. (That said, document databases not infrequently use pure JSON as their storage format.)

Comment: In the browser case, the browser does not request the full HTML file, but only the needed data? So the HTTP response only contains the XML/JSON containing only the desired data, and not the FULL updated HTML page?

Comment: If a browser requests a page, it expects HTML (the server can return something else, but then it'll become a save dialog rather than a web page). Within that page, though, you may have JavaScript running that issues more requests asynchronously. In that situation, most commonly JSON is used to supply updates, which the code then renders into HTML. It is also possible, but less common, for the server to directly generate the new HTML to store in the page (this is less common because it's less flexible, and tends to eat more bandwidth.) All of this is HTTP, what differs is the processing.

Comment: Worth pointing out is that HTTP itself does not offer any direct way to cough up partial updates to a document that's been returned -- by design, it's a stateless protocol with no notion of dynamic rendering. All incremental processing, if present, is due to client-side scripting of some form. (Newer protocols like web sockets aim to make this simpler for the client.)

Answer (score 0):

XML and JSON are common data formats for HTTP request and response bodies.

Sometimes they are used as storage formats for the data, but they are more commonly generated dynamically.

Comment: Let me try to extend your comment. So the server responds with an HTML page containing the new stock/weather info. Now, I assume the page contains javascript code that parses the XML chunk in the page and turn it something readable?

Comment: That would be a very unusual scenario. More commonly the server would respond with XML or JSON (not embedded in HTML at all) and the client application (which might be a JavaScript+HTML based SPA or might be something else entirely) would make use of the data … possibly turning it into something readable … possibly doing something else (like logging it against a time stamp for latter analysis of trends).

Comment: I get it now. I thought HTTP responses could only have HTML inside them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, surely using XML and JSON you can create and object on client (better yet in a common class that can be used both on server and client), populate the object with data and serialize it on client, send it over to server , de-serialize it to object again and use it. You can do the same with the result that the server had to pass back to the client.

JSON format is used for serializing and transmitting structured data over network connection. It is primarily used to transmit data between a server and web applications.